# Clearing text box fields on a page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, field

What should be a simple issue is stumping me for some reason. I am new to MVC so that should explain that.

I am trying to clear all fields on a page after a submit is entered.

I have seen the code below used in examples but dont know where to put it.  I tried it in my PersonModel.vb and it throws errors. I tried it in my Repository where I keep my subs and functions and it throws errors everytime over the word(s) ModelState and ValueProvierResult.

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("Key", new ValueProviderResult(null, string.Empty, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

Can someone offer some advice for me to clear out the fields(text boxes) on a page?  I am very new to MVC and could use some assistanct.

Thanks

LW

Here is the code....

```
<HttpPost(), MvcReCaptcha.CaptchaValidator()> _
Function Nominate(ByVal m As NominationModel, ByVal captchaValid As Boolean) As ActionResult

    Dim db = New ChampionTrees.Common.DataAccess.ChampionTreesRepository With {.UserName = "SYSTEM"}
    BindNominateDdls(db)

    Dim addPost As Boolean = False
    If (Request.Form("addNominator") <> Nothing) Then
        m.People.Add(New PersonModel With {.Indicator = PersonIndicator.Nominator})
        addPost = True
    ElseIf Request.Form("addOwner") <> Nothing Then
        m.People.Add(New PersonModel With {.Indicator = PersonIndicator.Owner})
        addPost = True
    Else
        For Each f In Request.Form.Keys
            If f.ToString.StartsWith("deletePerson") Then

                Dim idx = f.ToString.IndexOf("n")
                m.People.RemoveAt(Integer.Parse(f.ToString.Substring(idx + 1, f.ToString.Length - (idx + 1))))
                addPost = True
                Exit For

            End If
        Next
    End If

    If addPost Then

        For Each v In ModelState.Values.AsEnumerable()
            v.Errors.Clear()
        Next

        Return View(m)

    End If

    If m.Tree.Id < 0 AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.OtherName) Then

        Dim err As String = "Either a Common, Scientific, or Other Name must be provided."
        ModelState.AddModelError("Tree.Id", err)
        ModelState.AddModelError("OtherName", err)

    End If

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Measurement.CountyForester) = _
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Measurement.OtherCountyForester) Then

        Dim err As String = "A County Forester must be selected or entered (but not both)."
        ModelState.AddModelError("Measurement.CountyForester", err)
        ModelState.AddModelError("Measurement.OtherCountyForester", err)

    End If

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each p As PersonModel In m.People

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.EmailAddress) AndAlso _
            (p.Phone.Phone1 Is Nothing Or p.Phone.Phone2 Is Nothing Or p.Phone.Phone3 Is Nothing) Then

            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Format("People[{0}].Phone", i), "Either an E-mail Address or Phone number must be provided.")
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Format("People[{0}].Phone.Phone1", i), "")
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Format("People[{0}].Phone.Phone2", i), "")
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Format("People[{0}].Phone.Phone3", i), "")
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Format("People[{0}].EmailAddress", i), " ")

        Else

            Dim int As Integer = 0
            Dim err As Boolean = False

            If Not p.Phone.Phone1 Is Nothing AndAlso _
                            (p.Phone.Phone1.Length <> 3 Or Not Integer.TryParse(p.Phone.Phone1, Int)) Then

                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Format("People[{0}].Phone.Phone1", i), "")
                err = True
            End If
            If Not p.Phone.Phone2 Is Nothing AndAlso _
                            (p.Phone.Phone2.Length <> 3 Or Not Integer.TryParse(p.Phone.Phone2, int)) Then

                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Format("People[{0}].Phone.Phone2", i), "")
                err = True
            End If
            If Not p.Phone.Phone3 Is Nothing AndAlso _
                (p.Phone.Phone3.Length <> 4 Or Not Integer.TryParse(p.Phone.Phone3, int)) Then

                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Format("People[{0}].Phone.Phone3", i), "")
                err = True
            End If

            If err Then ModelState.AddModelError(String.Format("People[{0}].Phone", i), "Phone Number is not numeric.")

        End If

        If m.OwnershipType = Ownership.Public AndAlso _
            p.Indicator = PersonIndicator.Owner AndAlso _
            p.ParcelName Is Nothing Then
            ModelState.AddModelError(String.Format("People[{0}].ParcelName", i), "The Parcel Name field is required for public nominations.")
        End If

        i += 1

    Next

    If Not m.UseNominatorsAsOwners AndAlso _
        (From e In m.People Where e.Indicator = PersonIndicator.Owner Select e).Count = 0 Then
        ModelState.AddModelError("UseNominatorsAsOwners", "At least one Owner is required.")
    End If

    If Files.Count > 0 AndAlso Not m.ElectronicUseAgreement Then
        ModelState.AddModelError("ElectronicUseAgreement", "The Electronic Use Agreement must be agreed to.")
    End If

    If Not captchaValid Then
        ModelState.AddModelError("ReCaptcha", "You did not type the verification word correctly. Please try again.")
    End If

    If ModelState.IsValid Then

        ' load our uploads from session
        For Each f In Files
            f.Value.Viewable = m.ElectronicUseAgreement
            m.Uploads.Add(f.Value)
        Next

        ' insert the nomination into the db
        db.InsertNomination(m)

        ViewData("message") = "Nomination has been submitted"

    End If

    ModelState.Clear()
    Return View(m)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Hi you should be able to use: `ModelState.Clear()` and when you return the View all previous entered data will be cleared.

Edit:

Here's some example code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
{
  // This will clear whatever form items have been populated
  ModelState.Clear();

  return View();
}
```

Update 2:

In your code you are clearing the ModelState however your passing the Model (you've called it m) back to your view and your view is then picking this model and displaying its properties.

If for example I have a page which accepted a first name and last name and when I post I want to add this to a database but then return the same view but empty for my next request my code would look something like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person p)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // This will clear whatever form items have been populated
    ModelState.Clear();
    // Here I'm just returning the view I dont want a model being passed
    return View();
  }

  // Here I'm returning the model as there's an error and the user needs to see
  // what has been entered.
  return View(p);
}
```

Comment: When I try that it says "ModelState" is not declared. Where should I use that code?

Comment: I even tried it on the aspx page and it says ther is no Clear() method for ModelState......

Comment: I've updated with some sample code - if you still don't understand can you post your code. Thanks

Comment: I got it to accept ModelState.Clear(). I needed to add in the import for it but it did not clear the form. Nothing changed.

Comment: Can you post your controllers/actions please.

Comment: Here is some sample of what i have..................................

 If ModelState.IsValid Then

            ' load our uploads from session
            For Each f In Files
                f.Value.Viewable = m.ElectronicUseAgreement
                m.Uploads.Add(f.Value)
            Next

db.InsertNomination(m)

           ViewData("message") = "Nomination has been submitted"

        End If

        ModelState.Clear()
        Return View(m)

Comment: The code I listed above is inside a sub where I insert some data into the database.  I could only list part of the Sub because of the space limits here...

Comment: Just edit you original question with the code. You should do ModelState.Clear() in your action result before you return your view.

Comment: That got it.  I guess I didnt need to be sending back the "m" in the call to the view.  I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Or if the ModelState was valid you just can Redirect back to Get Action like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person p)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // do work and finally back to Get Action
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

  return View(p);
}
```

Comment: `ModelState.Clear()` didn't work for me. But this did.

Comment: thanks, its resolved my problem RedirectToAction("Index") instead of View();

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible you could use jQuery and do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").each(function(){
         $(this).val("");
    });
});
```

And maybe wrap that in some sort of is the form posted Razor code.

Comment: I wondered about jQuery.... haven't tried that yet.  I considered some code in the OnLoad event of the page but not sure you can do that with MVC.

Answer (score 2):

in Jquery

```
$("#btnID").click(function () {
    $("input[type=text]").val("");

});
```

`modelstate.clear()` after successful submission